# Storing objects in array of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have got a question regarding an assignment I need to finish. Basically I need to store coordinates in their respective objects and store them in an array. There are multiple sets of coordinates which all need a separate array, all these arrays again need to be stored in an array.

This is a simple version of what I'm trying to do, using 3 classes:

```
package test2;

import java.io.PrintStream;
//import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {

PrintStream out;

Test(){
    out = new PrintStream(System.out);
}

    Coordinate[] row = new Coordinate[5];
    CoordinateRow[] main = new CoordinateRow[10];

    void start(){


    row[0] = new Coordinate(4, 9);
    row[1] = new Coordinate(4, 1);
    row[2] = new Coordinate(0, 4);

    main[0] = new CoordinateRow(row);


    row[0] = new Coordinate(5, 3);
    row[1] = new Coordinate(7, 2);
    row[2] = new Coordinate(4, 8);


    main[1] = new CoordinateRow(row);

    out.println(main[0].row[0].y);




    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new Test().start();
}

}




package test2;


public class Coordinate{

    int x;
    int y;

    Coordinate(int x, int y){

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;     

    }
```

}

```
package test2;

import test2.Coordinate;


public class CoordinateRow {

    Coordinate[] row;

    CoordinateRow(Coordinate[] row){
        this.row = row;

    }
}
```

When i vary the values in the arrays in the print statement it always displays the last set of coordinates inserted.

I hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You're not showing us the real code, you're showing us code that doesn't compile, the code is not indented, making it hard to read, and the name choice (SubClass and SubClass2) is also awful, making it hard to understand what these classes are subbosed to be.

Comment: What exactly you need? Where are you changing x and y value?

Comment: Sorry, i meant the array indexes.

Comment: I changed the names to Coordinate and CoordinateRow, coordinate saves the x and y values of the coordinate, coordinateRow creates a set of coordinates

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same array `row`, this won't work because of passing reference instead of values. You should create new array. Both `main[0]` and `main[1]` contains the same reference

```
SubClass[] row = new SubClass[5];
SubClass[] row2 = new SubClass[5];
SubClass2[] main = new SubClass2[10];

void start(){


row[0] = new SubClass(4, 9);
row[1] = new SubClass(4, 1);
row[2] = new SubClass(0, 4);

main[0] = new SubClass2(row);


row2[0] = new SubClass(5, 3);
row2[1] = new SubClass(7, 2);
row2[2] = new SubClass(4, 8);


main[1] = new SubClass2(row2);

out.println(main[0].row[0].y);
```

}

this is only a part of code...

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain what the assignment is exactly, but thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: This is the assigment:

Start with the coordinates on the first row, add the coordinates of the
second row at the back, then add the coordinates of the third row in front etc.
Make a new Coordinate and CoordinateRow class for this assignment. The
latter class has methods to add a CoordinateRow in front or at the back and
methods to add a single Coordinate at the front or at the back.

Above are given a few rows of coordinates like:
5,4 4,9 8,7

hope this clarifies